# How to Save the user's language choice on buttons using SharedPreferences with restarting

Tags: java, android, button, sharedpreferences

I saved the language in sharedpreference and it seem to be saved successfully, but when i reopen the application it gets back to the default language "en", how to make the activity starts with the same language saved and chosen before, i have two buttons, each one restarts the activity with different language, English and Arabic.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Languages extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences prefs;
String languageToLoad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_languages);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("Language", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String L = prefs.getString("Language", "");
    languageToLoad = L;





}


public void language_en(View view) {
    languageToLoad = "en";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("Language", languageToLoad);
    editor.commit();
    Locale locale = new Locale(String.valueOf(languageToLoad));
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    Languages.this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, Languages.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Languages.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void language_ar(View view) {
    languageToLoad = "ar";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("Language", languageToLoad);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    Languages.this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, Languages.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    Intent intent = new Intent(Languages.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: before setContentView(R.layout.activity_languages), call your language setting methods..

Comment: Your code is not formatted well, please correct the format

Answer (score 0):

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.Locale;

    public class Languages extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String languageToLoad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        updateLanguage(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_languages);

    }

    public void  updateLanguage(Context context)
    {
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("Language", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String L = prefs.getString("Language", "");
        languageToLoad = L;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.setLocale(new Locale(languageToLoad));
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        } else {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
       }
    }


    public void language_en(View view) {
        languageToLoad = "en";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("Language", languageToLoad);
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Languages.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void language_ar(View view) {
        languageToLoad = "ar";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("Language", languageToLoad);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Intent intent = new Intent(Languages.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: It still saves the language, but when i restart the application it doesn't open with the language chosen.

Comment: @HadyElHawary I have updated the answer try it again.

Comment: move `updateLanguage()` to some global place, before starting any activity or fragment first call `updateLanguage()` for sent the lanaguge

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know if it's something wrong i do or what, i really appreciate your help, but it still doesn't work, could you clarify what you mean by global place? i'm still a beginner in coding and that thing drove me crazy, i just want to restart the app with the same language chosen, i didn't know it will be that hard :/

Comment: have you set language file for English and Arabic?I mean translation of each string that you are using?

Comment: Yeah, i made a language string and it changes successfully, it's just when i force stop the app or close it from the history the language gets back to the main language "English"